# Align divs to right with vertical align middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 table">
        <div class="middle">Title XPTO</div>
        <div class="middle">Display:</div>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option label="10" selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
            <option label="25" value="25">25</option>
            <option label="50" value="50">50</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    display: table !important;
}
.middle {
    display: table-cell !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/jkf2L49e/

I want to put the text "Display:" nearest to the `select` element. And the select must be right (position) as possible. What is the best way to do this and make it responsive?

Answer (score 1):

You should also make the `<select>` part of the table layout too, so just wrap it with another `<div>`. The markup would be like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 table">
    <div class="left">Title XPTO</div>
    <div class="middle">Display:</div>
    <div class="right">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option label="10" selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
            <option label="25" value="25">25</option>
            <option label="50" value="50">50</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

To align the text to the right, you can simply use `text-align:right` in the middle cell. The CSS would be like this (with tweaks that asked in the comments below).

```
.table {
    display: table;
}
.table > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.table .middle {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
.table select {
    width: auto;
}
```

Updated demo - https://jsfiddle.net/jkf2L49e/4/

Comment: This is the proper table layout - https://jsfiddle.net/jkf2L49e/2/ based on the code.

Comment: thanks for your reply but it's very close. And any solution to reduce the size of the `select`?

Comment: Also seems like it's missing a container div, well I'm not very familiar with Bootstrap, but looks like it - https://jsfiddle.net/jkf2L49e/4/

Comment: That's what i was looking for. I tried some approaches but `white-space: nowrap;` is the "key" :-). Please update your answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Yep, updated, we can get it all fixed at once if you asked the question clearer. Glad to see that it's all solved :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this complete code:

```css
.table {
    display: table !important;
}
.middle {
    display: table-cell !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.text-right{
  text-align:right;
}
```

Now add this class to the div that contains the text "Display"

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 table">
    <div class="middle">Title XPTO</div>
    <div class="middle text-right">Display:</div>
    <select class="form-control">
        <option label="10" selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
        <option label="25" value="25">25</option>
        <option label="50" value="50">50</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the difference compare to the other answer that posted already?

Answer (score 0):

Try following complete code. It would be best solutions.

```
<html>
```

.wrapper
{
width:100%;

}
.leftdiv{
width: 90%;
float:left;
}
.rightdiv{
width:8%;
float:right;
}

Title XPTO

```
<div class="rightdiv">Display:

    <select>
        <option label="10" selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
        <option label="25" value="25">25</option>
        <option label="50" value="50">50</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Mark answer as right answer if helpful to you.